# Regex need to grab file name along with directory file is stored in

Tags: regex, vb.net

I believe the regex expression I need would work in any language but I will be using it for VB.Net. I need it get grab the file name along with the directory it is in. I only need it to capture "TEST-couldbe1\FINAL-word.txt" from "A:\TEST2-maybe1\TEST-couldbe1\FINAL-word.txt". All the things I have tried captures everything up to the colon or just the filename with the \ . Best code I have is below, Thanks for your help.

```
\\(?:.(?!\\))+$
```

Comment: There's no need for Regex. You can use `String.Substring()`

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use regex at all. The `System.IO` namespace has all the required functionality. The following code does what you need:

```
Dim fullpath As String = "A:\TEST2-maybe1\TEST-couldbe1\FINAL-word.txt"

Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpath)
Dim fullDir As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullpath)
Dim fullParentDir As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullDir)

Dim finalStr As String = $"{fullDir.Substring(fullParentDir.Length + 1)}{IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{fileName}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```regex
\w\\([.\w\\-]+)
```

**Input**

`A:\TEST2-maybe1\TEST-couldbe1\FINAL-word.txt`

**Output**

[image]

Try at https://regex101.com/r/rwy8o6/1

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `\\(?:.(?!\\))+$` that you tried matches `\` and then 1+ times any character except `\`

This way it does not match what comes before the leading `\` so you can add matching that using a negated character class:

```
[^\\]+\\(?:.(?!\\))+$
```

But this pattern contains a part that is called a tempered greedy token `(?:.(?!\\))+` which makes it costly on performance and can be written using a negated character class:

```
[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPrlcY/1)

Or more specific with a dot in the filename:

```
[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\.[^\\.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8B4WqZ/1)

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your help, some really great answers!!